# Proper api response error handling in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to pull some api data and save it for later use

How would I properly handle errors, with this code block:

```
# import modules
import requests
import json
#test api data
url='https://pipl.ir/v1/getPerson'
#error handling
try:
    url_response = requests.get(url,timeout=3)
    url_response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("OOps: Something Else",err)
#json dictionary
json_data = url_response.json()
#print api json response
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

This works if I get a valid json response, if not, I get a return like

```
Http Error: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://google.com/fakesite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/telendrith/python/blapi.py", line 19, in <module>
    json_data = url_response.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And .. I'm back at square nothing.

Comment: printing `response.text` would be a start to help you debug

Comment: What is your expected output? The code is properly handling the requests exceptions.